# Saltstack cmd.run on minion and store output in a file on master

Tags: salt-stack, provisioning, consul, infrastructure

I ran 'consul keygen' on my consul server to get encryption key. I want to store that key on salt-master server and use it lather on other states for creating consul agents config file.

/srv/salt/consul-server.sls

`{% set consulMasterKey = salt['cmd.run']('consul keygen') %}`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly... 
You want to generate a key one time and store it for future usage.
So run the command to generate the key (not necessarily via salt), and save this key as a grain on your salt master / minions (depends who should access is) or in pillar file, then you can access it from any state.
grains are best for servers properties and pillar for group/environment properties (like if you want all windows servers to have a specific configuration).

set grain (command line):

```
salt 'your-salt-master/minion' grains.append consulKey youKey
```

get grain value (from command line):

```
salt 'your-salt-master/minion' grains.get consulKey
```

get grain value (from state):

```
{%- set key = salt['grains.get']('consulKey') %}
```

get pillar value (from state):

```
{%- set key = salt['pillar.get']('consulKey') %}
```